# Must light helpers be added directly to scene?

Tags: three.js

Following method of adding light helper works ok:

```
var light = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xFFFFFF );
light.position.set(100,100,100);
scene.add(light);
var helper = new THREE.SpotLightHelper( light );
scene.add(helper);
```

but following will cause helper to be off position:

```
var wrapper = new THREE.Object3D();
wrapper.position.set(100,100,100);
var light = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xFFFFFF );
wrapper.add(light);
var helper = new THREE.SpotLightHelper( light );
wrapper.add(helper);
scene.add(wrapper);
```

It seems like helper position is taken from absolute light position to scene, but is then applied from it's wrapper, that means it is actually applied twice a thus doesn't match actual position of the light. In this example, helper would appear on (200,200,200). Same applies for PointLight and probably other light types.

Is it possible to put helpers into wrapper together with light and avoid position problem?

see it demonstrated here:  http://jsfiddle.net/wfpxdw37/24/

Comment: Since you have a concrete example, I would open an issue with three.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Light Helpers are just that -- helpers.

They must be added as a child of the scene.

Consider that requirement a feature. :-)

three.js r.69